# Expandable jquery div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried numerous examples here to make expandable div when clicking link item. My requrements are to have two link items and each opens one div. This is what I have tried so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="holder">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="link" href="#bla" data-link="first">show onde div content</a>/li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#bla" data-link="second">show another div content</a></li>
  </ul>

<div class="opis" data-link="first">
  tekst 1 
</div>

<div class="opis" data-link="second">
  tekst 2
</div>
```

**javascript/jQuery**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.opis').hide();

 $('.link').click(function() {
     $('.opis').hide();       
     $('.opis[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
         width: '200px'
      }, 300);
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

`.opis {display:none;}`

This is working fine.
is it possible to make it also retract on same link click? Maybe to add effect that it changes text to something else?
I use this on many `div`s and the only difference is the data-link attribute which is changed accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried to use the jquery ui resize. http://api.jqueryui.com/size-effect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done what you're asking with [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) which might be a little overkill for your situation, but it's more flexible than using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`:

```
$('.opis').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $element = $('.opis[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']');
    if($element.is(":visible")) {
        $element.fadeToggle({
            width: '200px'
        }, 300);
    } else {
        $('.opis').hide();
        $element.fadeToggle({
            width: '200px'
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2U73A/)

**EDIT**: updated with a little cleaner code:

```
$('.opis').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $element = $('.opis[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']');
    if(!$element.is(":visible")) {
        $('.opis').hide();
    }
    $element.fadeToggle({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2U73A/1/)

**EDIT 2**:

Updated to save the text in a hidden 'holder' div, when the fadetoggle happens, the text changes to either "Close me!" if it opens a div, or back to the original if it's not visible anymore.

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2U73A/2/)

Comment: thank you m8 this is exactly what i need... do you maybe know if its posible to change ahref "show one div content" and "show another div content " to something like "retract 1st",and for second "retract second" or its compblicated? anyways really apriciate this. just what i was looking for

Comment: Updated my answer with a new fiddle. Take a look, should work like you want it.

Comment: im sorry samsquanch for bothering you... im really gratefull..yes that does the trick..only thing is that even if i click on "close me" - it retracts div.. but "close me" stays.. it doesnt change back to original name of link :/

Comment: It's doing this in the fiddle I posted? I'm unable to make it stay "Close me!" once the div is faded out.

Comment: aaaah sorry... problem is in that div holdertekst.. i need to put it somewhere..i dont know what he actually does since he is outside of rest of the content :D i will fin place for him. thnx

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, like this?

**This example will display the information for 1.5 seconds, then disappear.**

```
 $('.link').click(function() {
     $('.opis').hide();       
     $('.opis[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
         width: '200px'
      }, 300).delay(1500).fadeOut();
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/95y5M/)</kbd>

---

Or, were you thinking more like this?

**This example will swap the information in the div based on which link is clicked.** All links use the same `opis`-class div to display their info.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/95y5M/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="holder">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="link" href="#bla" data-link="first">show onde div content</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#bla" data-link="second">show another div content</a></li>
  </ul>

<div class="opis" data-link="first">
  tekst 1 
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.opis').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.opis').hide();
    var dl = $(this).attr('data-link');
    if (dl == 'first'){
        $('.opis').html('<p id="house">You should buy a house</p>');
        $('.opis').fadeIn({width: '200px'}, 300);
    }else if (dl == 'second') {
        $('.opis').html('<p id="hamburger">You should buy a hamburger</p>');
        $('.opis').fadeIn({width: '200px'}, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: really appriciate the answer. i used the one from samsquanch. it fits me better

Comment: @Emanuel Thanks for the comment, Emanuel (great name, btw - very historical). Please remember to accept Samsquanch's answer (to close the question) and, if you have time, also to upvote any answers that were helpful to you. Doing so costs you nothing (in fact, accepting an answer is worth +2 rep) and helps others. Best wishes with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I was exactly in your shoes... till I have this solution which I strongly advise you to use  [here](http://sylvain-hamel.github.io/simple-expand/)

It should do what you are attempts to and it's perfect if you have more than one expand/collapse divs

---

**added information**

**Instruction:**

in the header add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/redhotsly/simple-expand/master/src/simple-expand.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/redhotsly/simple-expand/master/src/simple-expand.min.js"></script>
```

in the body insert the following in the place you want to have the expand/collapse div

`<a class="expander" href="#">click me</a><div class="content">content to hide.</div>`

and Just before the  insert the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('.expander').simpleexpand();
        prettyPrint();
});
</script>
```

Optional, add this to your css file:

```
.content {display:none;}
```

You can change the look and feel to meet your requirements..